# Python Two Custom Sort By Two String Variables

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have a dataframe:

```
data = {
    'group': ['2', '1', '2', '2', '2', '1'],
    'interval': ['20-30', '20-30', '30-40', '10-20', '10-20', '0-10'],
    'count': [3, 4, 2, 7, 5, 1],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
group   interval    count
2          20-30    3
1          20-30    4
2          30-40    2
2          10-20    7
2          10-20    5
1          0-10     1
```

I want to sort `group` first then `interval` simultaneously in ascending order which will look like this:

```
group   interval    count
1       00-10   1
1       20-30   4
2       10-20   5
2       10-20   7
2       20-30   3
2       30-40   2
```

I know how to do this separately but how to do it simultaneously?

```
(
    df
    .sort_values(by = ['group'], key = lambda s: s.str[0:].astype(int))
    .sort_values(by = ['interval'], key = lambda s: s.str[:2].astype(int))
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

Comment: Doesn't this work for you? ```df.sort_values(["group", "interval"])```

Comment: No it does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use different custom keys in the same [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) call, you could use a dictionary:

```
keys = {'group': lambda s: s.str[0:].astype(int),
        'interval': lambda s: s.str[:2].astype(int)
       }

df.sort_values(by=['group', 'interval'],
               key=lambda x: keys[x.name](x),
               ignore_index=True)
```

Or with a custom function:

```
def cust_sort(s):
    match s.name:
        case 'group':
            return s.str[0:].astype(int)
        case 'interval':
            return s.str[:2].astype(int)
        case _:
            return s

df.sort_values(by=['group', 'interval'],
               key=cust_sort,
               ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
  group interval  count
0     1    00-10      1
1     1    20-30      4
2     2    10-20      7
3     2    10-20      5
4     2    20-30      3
5     2    30-40      2
```